# Do we group reversible reaction with all reactants and product solid as homogenous or heterogeneous equilibrium?

Tags: equilibrium, phase

My personal thought is that they should be in heterogenous equilibrium as we define it as all reactants and products being of different phase (phase-their must not be a visible boundary) and solids clearly have a visible separation.

Comment: It can be either way, depending on reaction.

Comment: Good luck to identify one such reaction.

Comment: [Tin pest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin_pest)?

Comment: Well there are reactions with both solids such as reaction between carbon(graphite) and carbon(diamond) and the reaction lies under heterogenous equilibrium as graphite and diamond are different phases of carbon. I want to know, should this be the case for all solid reactants and products reaction?